# Срабатывание события

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Может кто подскажет и подскажет: никак не пойму почему не срабатывает событие. Использую в первом поле стандартный jquery слайдер (ползунок) привязанный к инпуту. При выборе радио и вводе вручную значения инпута все ок, а вот когда передвигаеш ползунок значение в инпуте меняется но ончендж не срабатывает.

```
<input type="text" id="quantity" onchange="clc();" class="quantity" 
name="quantity">
<div id="slider-gorizontal"></div>

<input  type="radio" name="thickness" onchange="clc();" class="choiceBtn 
thickness" value="260" checked="checked">Стандартная: 0.4 мм</input>

<input type="radio" name="thickness" onchange="clc();" class="choiceBtn 
thickness" value="335">Утолщенная: 0.5 мм</input>

function clc() {
    var q = $('#quantity').val();
    var t = $('.thickness:checked').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'calc.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {quantity:q, thickness:t},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function ( data ) {
          console.log ( data ) ;
          if(t == 260) {
                $('#result').empty();
                $('#result').append(data);
            }
            else{
                $('#result2').empty();
                $('#result2').append(data);
            }
        }
    });
}

  $( function() {
            $( "#slider-gorizontal" ).slider({
                range: "min",
                min: 0,
                max: 1000,
                value: 500,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#quantity" ).val( ui.value );
                }
                }).height('10');
            $( "#quantity" ).val( $( "#slider-gorizontal" ).slider( "value" ) );
        } );
```

Comment: Давайте код навешивания слайдера

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Программное изменение значение инпута не вызывает события `onchange`. Чтобы в этом убедиться, попробуйте:

```html
<input id='test' onchange='console.log(value);' />
<button onclick="document.getElementById('test').value='aaa';">Click</button>
```

Используйте событие `change` слайдера: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change